# I want to make the legend box horizontal for r bar plot but ncol is not working

Tags: r, resize, bar-chart, legend

This is the code I am using for the plot

```
barplot(read_comments_vs_influenced, xlab='Do you usually read comments under YouTube video clips?',ylab='Count',
        main=str_wrap("How far comments influence respondents' opinion for each category in reading  comments under Youtube videos",width = 110)
        ,legend=rownames(Age_vs_platform_follow_artists),
        args.legend = list(x = "topleft", cex = 0.4) )
```

I want to make the legend box horizontal to fit in the chart or make the box smaller without affecting the size of the font inside the legend
I tried to use ncol=3 but it gives me an error : ncol not a graphical argument
[image: plot]

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
barplot(read_comments_vs_influenced, xlab='Do you usually read comments under YouTube video clips?',ylab='Count',
        main=str_wrap("How far comments influence respondents' opinion for each category in reading  comments under Youtube videos",width = 110)
        )

legend("topleft", legend = rownames(Age_vs_platform_follow_artists),
        ncol = 3, cex = 0.4)
```

Maybe `ncol` was placed on the wrong side of a bracket?